# Would it create 100 objects without destroying older ones?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to experiment with node.js object life cycle and got a quick question. What do you think looking at the following code if **b()** will create 100 objects without destroying them?

```
function a() {
    this.init = function() {
        console.log('this is me!');
    };
}

function b() {
    (new a()).init();
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   b();
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this yourself?

Comment: Currently I am getting used to a Unit Testing tool and I am not sure how to test this up. I am very new to node.js at the moment.

Comment: JavaScript is garbage collected; you don't know when an object is "destroyed." But since those objects are _unreachable_, they're effectively candidates for garbage collection.

Comment: ok you mean I don't need to worry about performance assuming this b() will be called by server thousands of times?

Comment: There's a lot more to performance than just how many objects are in memory, so I can't _guarantee_ that. It's possible. But the basic point is you don't know when an object is destroyed, so the answer to the question you ask in the title is: "it depends."